# GEE - Add image band (NDVI) from one ImageCollection to corresponding image in an other ImageCollection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I have two ImageCollections one from Sentinel-1 and the other from Sentinel-2. From S-2 i derive the NDVI. I want to add the NDVI band from the S2 Collection to the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection with the closest date. How can i do this?

[GEE basic script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/577880f1c3b2f5d7fa2174520866b5fd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achive that. I would do that like this:

```
// map over the sentinel 1 collection
var appendNDViband = s1_grd_iw_vv_des.map(function(image){
  var dateS1 = ee.Number(image.get('system:time_start'));
  // map over the sentinel 2 collection 
  var appendAbsDifference = s2_cf_ndvi.select('NDVI').map(function(image){
    var dateS2 = ee.Number(image.get('system:time_start'));
    return image.set('absDifference', dateS2.subtract(dateS1).abs());
  });
  // calculate the image with the least absolute time difference
  var minDifference = appendAbsDifference.sort('absDifference').first();
  return image.addBands(minDifference)
              .set('propsS2', minDifference.toDictionary(minDifference.propertyNames().add('system:time_start')));
});

print('Sentinel-1 with NDVI band', appendNDViband);
```

Note that there will be differences in geometry and projection you will run into. Moreover, Sentinel 2 images are divided into MGRS tiles, you probably want to merge following [this](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca6590755ed16c066a3abff7e61a64f4) example.

[link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba3ef3d0fae76d54bdc8e45160bafd93)